# How do I fix the problem with the telebot?

Tags: python

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import commands

import telebot

import CONFIGS

# bot token
bot = telebot. TeleBot('CONFIGS.token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'TEXT', parser_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Error:

> bot = telebot. TeleBot('CONFIGS.token')
> AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you have the correct telebot library (`pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`)
2. Remove the space between `telebot.` and `TeleBot` in `bot = telebot. TeleBot('CONFIGS.token')`
3. Refer to the documentation (https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)
4. If you still have the same issue, open an issue on the GitHub repository.